# TImage gif refresh during stuff

Tags: multithreading, delphi, gif, freeze

I have a form (`BorderStyle = bsNone`) with just a `TImage` as background. The `TImage` has a GIF loaded.

After calling `Show()`, I start a process where I use `TSHFileOpStruct` to copy file.
When the copy is finished, the program terminates.

The problem is that, when the copy starts, the GIF is frozen until the process is finished.
I would use `TSHFileOpStruct` because it's very efficient when there is a lot of files and big sizes.

Do you have any suggestion?

I have tried to use `Application.Processmessages()` before or after the execution of `TSHFileOpStruct` object, but nothing changes.

Comment: Why are you tagging [multithreading] when you don't use it!? But it would be the solution to your problem, to use a thread where you do the copy stuff.

Comment: When you give answers to your own questions..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason everything freezes is because you are performing the file copy in the context of the main UI thread, blocking the message loop until the operation is finished. The UI, including the GIF, requires the message loop to remain active to handle painting and animation requests.

You need to either:

- move your copy logic to a separate worker thread, via `TThread` or `TTask`, so you are not blocking the main UI thread anymore.
- switch to a different API, such as `IFileOperation` or `CopyFileEx()`, that allows to you receive status callbacks *during* the file copy. `SHFileOperation()` does not support that. This way, you can call `TForm.Update()` or `Application.ProcessMessages()` *during* the copying to keep your UI responsive.